# How to draw hasse diagram - divisibility - R and inverse R

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I don't know how to draw the Hasse diagram for divisibility on the sets.

A = {2,3,4,5,6,9,10}

R is partially ordered set for set A. R = {(a,b) | a divides b}

How to draw a hasse diagram about R and inverse R?

Please answer with picture.

Comment: You’re dealing with a different set, but the principles were laid out in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250496/how-to-draw-hasse-diagram-for-divisibilty/250515#250515) to a similar question.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I have a additional question. When I draw a hasse diagram about [inverse R], maybe I just change the top and bottom of the hasse diagram about [R]. Is it right?

// R = {(a,b) | a divides b}

Comment: Yes, the Hasse diagram for $R^{-1}$ just turns the Hasse diagram for $R$ upside down.

Comment: Thank you for your answering! I solved it.

Comment: You’re welcome!